# Is there an easy way to see why any periodic function can be written as a sum $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} $

Tags: fourier-series

Somehow taylor series make sense to me but I can not clearly see why any periodic function can be written as a sum of trigonometric series or complex exponentials. Whenever I see 'explanations' of Fourier series it is just said that it is possible.

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{inx} $$

Comment: Because it's a basis for the appropriate function space, as can be seen by taking inner products.

Comment: It isn't. You need $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}.$

Comment: An abstract reason is: $e^{inx}$ forms an orthonormal basis for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.  Perhaps you will learn about this framework in the future.